# Docusaurus | ValidationError: "authorsMapPath" is not allowed

Tags: docusaurus

I wanna try to use the global "authors" in the blog markdown file "authorsMapPath" this parameter in the `docusaurus.config.js` file.

However, whatever I tried in the presets or plugins, I always got this error.

```
A validation error occured.
The validation system was added recently to Docusaurus as an attempt to avoid user configuration errors.
We may have made some mistakes.
If you think your configuration is valid and should keep working, please open a bug report.

ValidationError: "authorsMapPath" is not allowed
```

Here is my partial setting in the `docusaurus.config.js` file.

```
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          // sidebarCollapsible: true,
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js'),
          // Please change this to your repo.
          editUrl:
            'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/edit/master/website/',
        },
        blog: {
          // authorsMapPath: 'authors.yml',
          showReadingTime: true,
          // Please change this to your repo.
          editUrl:
            'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/edit/master/website/blog/',
        },
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/plugin-content-blog',
      {
        authorsMapPath: 'authors.yml',
        // Simple use-case: string editUrl
        // editUrl: 'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/edit/main/website/',
        // Advanced use-case: functional editUrl
        
      },
    ],
  ],
```

Is there any idea about my error?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue after I upgraded `@docusaurus/preset-classic` version from `2.0.0-alpha.72` to `2.0.0-beta.21`.

The code became like below:

```
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          // sidebarCollapsible: true,
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js'),
          // Please change this to your repo.
          editUrl:
            'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/edit/master/website/',
        },
        blog: {
          authorsMapPath: 'authors.yml',
          showReadingTime: true,
          // Please change this to your repo.
          editUrl:
            'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/edit/master/website/blog/',
        },
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
```